# visibleWhen project has a particular facet

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I need to add a menu item in project explorer and should be visible only when the project has particular facet. Menu item is added but visibility step isn't working.

How can I do this?

plugin.xml:

```xml
<menuContribution
    locationURI="popup:myMenu?after=additions">
    <command
        commandId="someCommandID"
        label="SomeCommandLabel"
        style="push">
<visibleWhen>
  <with variable="selection">
    <iterate operator="and" ifEmpty="false">
      <test property="org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.facets" 
              value="SomeFacet" />
    </iterate>
 </with>
</visibleWhen>
    </command>
</menuContribution>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct `test` for a project facet is:

```xml
<test 
  forcePluginActivation="true"
  property="org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.projectFacet"
  value="facet id"/>
```

Comment: Any way to restrict this to a particular facet and not its sub types?

i have a face 'A', if I set the value in the above code as A, all its dependent facets also were effected. I need it only on A not the dependents..

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea. Ask a new question someone else may know.